# How to change the graphic of the SDK Sample "Compass"?

Tags: android

I m using this sample for android sdk  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Compass.html

In that sample,the compass is like that

[image]

I would like to use a graphic for the compass as this one for example [image]

Is that possible?Maybe my question is stupid but i have never used graphics like that before!Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, instead of using `canvas.drawPath()` in the example, replace it with a call to [canvas.drawBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Matrix,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) where the bit map you pass is the graphic you want to display. Note there are multiple `drawBitmap()` methods. Use which ever one best suites your needs.

Comment: so i have to use drawBitmap(R.id.image);?

Comment: Yea, if `image` corresponds to the images stored in your resources that you want to display.

Comment: if i want to get the image from my drawable folder?

Answer (score 0):

The compass sample uses drawPath, unless I'm wrong. You should be able to change that to use drawImage instead, and point it at your image: add your image (in png format) to the res/drawable folder and check out the javadocs for the Cavas.drawImage method (sorry, on the mobile so can't conveniently insert a javadoc link).